# for loop, iteration through alphabet? java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, iteration, alphabet

I can iterate through the alphabet, but I'm trying to keep the last iteration and add on the next letter.
this is my code.

```
for(char alphabet = 'a'; alphabet <='z'; alphabet ++ )
        {

            System.out.println(alphabet);
        }
```

I want it to print out something that looks like this.

a

ab

abc

abcd

abcde..... and so forth. How is this possible?

Comment: Create a string variable and concatenate it with the current letter...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to add the `char alphabet` to a string.

```
String output = "";

for(char alphabet = 'a'; alphabet <='z'; alphabet++ )
    {
        output += alphabet;
        System.out.println(output);
    }
```

This should work for you ;)

Comment: Never use `String += String` in a loop. Use `StringBuilder`. Sure, this is a small inconsequential loop, but start doing it the right way, so it becomes second nature.

Comment: i edited like 2 seconds after i posted lol! such fast response time haha. One thing to note. the output += alphabet needs to be inside the print statement  System.out.println(output += alphabet);

Comment: I don't think that has to be in the System.out. Why do you think so?

Comment: @pewpew Sure that's shorter, but "needs to be"? No.

Comment: Ok i see what you did there ;)

Comment: @pewpew Of all the answers, you accept the one with the worst performance of them all. It *is* a bit simpler to write than the rest, I'll give you that. It's a good thing there's only 26 letters in the alphabet.

Answer (score 9):

I will go with [StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) or [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). Something like:

`StringBuffer`

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for (char alphabet = 'a'; alphabet <= 'z'; alphabet++) {
    sb.append(alphabet);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

`StringBuilder`

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char alphabet = 'a'; alphabet <= 'z'; alphabet++) {
    sb.append(alphabet);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

**String vs StringBuffer vs StringBuilder**:

**String**: It is immutable, so when you do any modification in the string, it will create new instance and will eatup memory too fast.

**StringBuffer**: You can use it to create dynamic String and at the sametime only 1 object will be there so very less memory will be used. It is synchronized (which makes it slower).

**StringBuilder**: It is similar to StringBuffer. The olny difference is: it not synchronized and hence faster.

So, better choice would be **StringBuilder**. [Read more](http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2013/06/difference-between-string-stringbuilder.html).

Using `Java 8`

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

IntStream.range('a', 'z').forEach(i -> {
    sb.append((char) i);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
});
```

Comment: `StringBuffer` is obsolete. Use `StringBuilder`. Quoting [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html): *"As of release JDK 5, `StringBuffer` has been supplemented with an equivalent class designed for use by a single thread, `StringBuilder`."*

Comment: I have added both in my solution.

Comment: `StringBuffer` is synchronized, which makes it slower. Unless you're in an extremely rare situation where multiple threads append to the same buffer, you should never use it. Always use `StringBuilder`. Make it a habit. I'd suggest removing `StringBuffer` from answer, so as not to misguide any newbie Java developers coming here.

Comment: @Andreas I dont suggest removing I would suggest the Ambrish should clarify the difference so that OP can choose any method accoding the requirement

Comment: @Andreas  I have added details and also better solution: Java8.

Comment: Java 8 stream is a nice touch, but I disagree with calling it a "better solution". To me, it's actually slightly worse, but I'd be good with simply calling it "another" way of doing it.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest using a `StringBuilder`:

```
// Using StringBuilder
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
    System.out.println(buf.append(c).toString());
```

You could also do it slightly faster by using a `char[]`, however `StringBuilder` is more obvious and easier to use:

```
// Using char[]
char[] arr = new char[26];
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    arr[i] = (char)('a' + i);
    System.out.println(new String(arr, 0, i + 1));
}
```

Alternatives that you shouldn't use:

- `StringBuffer`: Same as `StringBuilder`, but synchronized, so slower.
- `s = s.concat(new String(c))`: Allocates 2 Strings per iteration, instead of only 1.
- `s += c`: Internally `+=` is compiled to `s = new StringBuilder().append(s).append(c).toString()`, so horrendously slow with *exponential* response times.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "" ;  
for(char alphabet = 'a'; alphabet <='z'; alphabet ++ )
        {
            s = s.concat(String.valueOf(alphabet));
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```

Comment: I am assuming he will declare it outside of that for loop :). Anyways edited the answer

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it's not really a good answer, since it doesn't teach the OP. Instead it gives an alternative solution without explanation. This will usually lead to OP not learning, and coming back for asking a new question when a similar problem occurs. Would you mind adding some explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Offtopic, Using `Java 8` [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToObj-java.util.function.IntFunction-) it is as simple as:

```
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");
 "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".chars().mapToObj(i -> builder.append((char) i))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Usage:**

```
 public class AlphabetsLooping {
    static final String input = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");
    input.chars().mapToObj(i -> builder.append((char) i))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually to use `IntStream.range`
You would need to add `+1` **to have last letter Z**

So, it would be

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

IntStream.range('a', 'z'+1).forEach(i -> {
    sb.append((char) i);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
});
```